# able to run shell script but not curl commands from java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, linux, shell, curl, libcurl

I am trying to make a curl POST from java through java's Runtime. When I run a shell script with the command "curl -vF etc" in it, the code runs as expected, but if I try pulling the command into java as a properly escaped string it gives the following exception/error
"Protocol "http not supported or disabled in libcurlcurl""

```
String cmd = "./go.sh";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
//etc...
```

vs

```
String cmd = "curl -vF etc";//found in go.sh
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
//etc...
```

output

```
"Curl Executed Correctly"
//proprietary
```

vs

```
* Protocol "http not supported or disabled in libcurlcurl: (1) Protocol "http not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Comment: Give us a little bit of code and output please.

Comment: How about expanding the etc part?

Comment: The error message looks like you have `"http:` rather than just `http:` - I guess you are double-quoting stuff which shouldn't be double-quoted.

Comment: thanks tripleee for some reason it wanted not quotes in the line unless I type it directly in the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short bit of googling show's [this page](http://17thdegree.com/archives/2008/02/26/protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl/).  Which would indicate that you're string isn't right.